# How to modify laravel file upload code to work on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, hosting, shared-hosting

I am working on this small laravel project where users need to upload files.
The upload code works fine locally. But fails to work on shared hosting since the directory structure is different.
I use the following line of code to specify where the uploaded file would go

```
$path = public_path().'/assets/users/'.$request->user()->id;
```

Locally the file goes to the public folder(public/assets/users/user_id)
of my laravel app. But on shared hosting, it is not allowed to modify the laravel `public` folder instead it has a `public_html` which has read/write permissions.
How can I modify the path to work on shared hosting or how do I make it use
`public_html/assets` instead of trying to use `/home/my_user_name/project_folder/public/assets` which is not permitted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to move whole project to **public_html** folder.

You public path should looks like

```
../some_path/public_html/laravel_app/public
```

And you point this path to set vhost

Problem solves itself.

Comment: Is the whole project save in the public_html folder? Isn't the code vulnerable?